# DateTime.add methods doesnt change the year field in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  print(date);
  date.add(new Duration(days:365));
  print(date);
```

this code outputs the result below

```
2020-12-14 22:44:58.149
2020-12-14 22:44:58.149
```

Instead of 2020, I want the result to be 2021. I want to change the year field if the days in the year is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.add` returns a new `DateTime`, therefore the correct usage would be:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
print(date);
date = date.add(new Duration(days:365));
print(date);
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, It really helped. Thanks a lot

Comment: You’re welcome! Don’t forget to select the answer as correct :)